# is it possible to reproduce python's string interpolation in ocaml?

Tags: ocaml, printf

In python, one can use printf like formatting with the "%" operator:

```
"i am %d years old" % 99
```

or

```
"%s is %d years old" % ("bob", 101)
```

Is there a way to get the same concise syntax in Ocaml, for arbitrary numbers of arguments?

For a single argument, the following works:

```
let (%) = Printf.sprintf in ... "i am %d years old" % 99
```

Is there a way that works for arbitrary numbers of arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, it does not seem any more difficult to use a format to produce the type `(typ1 * typ2 * ... * typn) -> string` than `typ1 -> typ2 -> ... -> typn -> string`. That is, perhaps, with the exception of recursive formats `%( fmt %)`. Does anyone actually use those?

In practice, though, the OCaml implementors chose the latter form, and implemented typesystem hacks for that form, not for the former one. So I am afraid the answer is that short of patching the compiler, you're stuck with the [curried](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) form of format string substitution.

Answer (score 8):

It depends what you mean by arbitrary numbers of arguments:

- I don't believe there is a way to write a function in OCaml that can accept *and unpack* a tuple of arbitrary arity (e.g., both `(1, "bob")` and `("joe", "bob", "briggs")`).
- The Caml Way of handling multiple arguments is *not* through tuples but by currying.  If you're willing to do that, then you can just use `Printf.sprintf`.
- If you really want an infix operator, e.g., something like

  ```
  "%s-%s %s is the best movie reviewer" % "joe" "bob" "briggs"
  ```

  then you're out of luck, because **function application binds tighter than any infix operator**.   You could write

  ```
  ("%s-%s %s is the best movie reviewer" % "joe") "bob" "briggs"
  ```

  but to me that seems kind of beside the point—not the droids you're looking for.

So if your question is:

> Can I define, in Objective Caml, an *infix* version of `sprintf` that accepts an arbitrary number of arguments?

The answer is **no.**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by a prefix op, instead of infix:

```
let (!%) = Printf.sprintf
```

If you want just a concise way of writing sprintf, it is enough.

As Tobu mentioned you require P4 if you want Python like special syntax. I believe it must be too complicated.